# Can't see the welcome page when deploying JSF2 app in tomcat

Tags: java, jsf, maven, tomcat, jsf-2

I want to deploy my JSF2 app on tomcat using `mvn tomcat:run`. I did compile it correctly previously using the `mvn clean install` command. 
Tomcat is saying to me `INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080`

I wonder if I did configure my welcome page correctly.
This is my **web.xml**:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">

    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>home.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>


</web-app>
```

And this is my **pom.xml** just to double check that the artifactid is correct:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.bogus</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf2_tutorial</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>jsf2_tutorial Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
            <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0-b03</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0-b03</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Just i am going to paste the last bit, the **home.xhtml** to make sure it is also correct:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <title>Hello JSF 2!</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
       #{welcome.message}
    </h:body>
</html>
```

The error when I navigate to the welcome page is:

```
HTTP status 500
In the url I notice I had a typo. Now I enter the correct URL but the problem is:

    type Exception report

    message

    description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

    exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Class javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet is not a Servlet
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

root cause

java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet cannot be cast to javax.servlet.Servlet
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

    note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/6.0.29 logs.
```

**Update**

I got rid of the exception by removing the servlet-api dependency from the pom.xml

```
 <dependency>  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId> 
 <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>  <version>2.5</version> 
 </dependency>
```

The page now loads but the message is not being displayed. 
This is how the java part of this app looks like:

```
package org.bogus;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

@ManagedBean(name = "welcome", eager = true)
public class WelcomeBean {
    public WelcomeBean() {
        System.out.println("WelcomeBean instantiated");
    }
    public String getMessage() {
        return "I'm alive!";
    }
}
```

This example is almost the same as in the official JSF tutorial at oracle: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjaam.html

I included the `<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>` but still I don't see the message in the console or in the page. 
Maybe there is still something wrong with the configurations.
Any idea?

**Update**
I just included the `faces-config.xml` file under `WEB-INF` but still does not work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This file is not required if you don't need any extra configuration. -->
<faces-config version="2.1"
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_1.xsd">

   <!-- Write your navigation rules here. -->

   <application>
        <locale-config>
            <default-locale>en</default-locale>
            <supported-locale>en</supported-locale>
        </locale-config>
   </application>

</faces-config>
```

Comment: In my deleted answer, I said to use the `web.xml` servlet version which matches the container's own servlet version. For Tomcat 6 it's Servlet 2.5. You told that it didn't work which I assumed to be a Maven thing. But now you've updated your question to edit the `web.xml` to be Servlet 3.0 instead of 2.3. But it should be Servlet 2.5 as explained in my deleted answer. If you use an unsupported servlet version, then the container will run in fallback modus matching the lowest supported servlet version.

Comment: @BalusC I just updated the question, I changed to version 2.5, but I see some exception related to the Servlet. Not sure I think I did change the version correctly

Comment: The exception is definitely helpful. The initialization of JSF is now successfully triggered, but it ultimately failed due to a corrupt classpath. Your Maven build is definitely corrupt. I don't do Maven, but ultimately, the `/WEB-INF/lib` folder of the Maven-produced WAR file/structure should contain **only** the `jsf-api`, `jsf-impl`, `jstl-api`, `jstl-impl` JARs and not others, definitely not a `servlet-api` which the exception seems to suggest. I guess that you've to declare the Servlet API in the `provided` scope (as in, it's already provided by the target container, which is Tomcat).

Comment: @BalusC I am confused, my `WEB-INF` does not contain a `lib` folder. 
Should I create it? The only things in my `WEB-INF` at the moment are a folder called `classes`(this contains the `beans.xml`) and the `web.xml` file

Comment: @BalusC I think I am getting close. I removed the following dependency from the `pom.xml` `<dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
   <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
   <version>2.5</version>
  </dependency>` Now there is no exception, the page seems to load but the message is not being displayed. I will update the with the Java class

Comment: @BalusC I also just tried making the managed bean implement `Serializable` but still cant see the message on the screen. 
I don't know what it could be. Is there any configuration left to do?

Comment: Do *View Source* in browser. Do you see unparsed JSF XHTML code or do you see generated HTML code?

Comment: @BalusC I see HTML code `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
        <title>Hello JSF 2!</title></head><body>
       
    </body>
</html>`

Comment: Okay, the `FacesServlet` did successfully do its job. Only the managed bean is simply not found. Do you have a JSF 2.0 compatible `faces-config.xml`? This is required in order to `@ManagedBean` and likes to work.

Comment: @BalusC No I dont have a `faces-config.xml`

Comment: @BalusC I just added an empty faces-config.xml that looks like this:
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This file is not required if you don't need any extra configuration. -->
<faces-config version="2.0"
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd">

   <!-- Write your navigation rules here. -->

</faces-config>`But is not working,  is the version correct? Maybe I should put 2.1

Comment: @BalusC I just tried using both verion 2.0 and 2.1 but still I don't see the message when I go to `http://localhost:8080/jsf2_tutorial/home.xhtml`

Comment: Complete absence of `faces-config.xml` file is also fine. Point is, if you have one, it should be at least JSF 2.0 compatible. Well, if it still doesn't create the bean, then I don't know. At least the `eager=true` is unnecessary and the absence of the scope is strange, but it should still be constructed and invoked. You've surely successfully created JSF2 projects before, right? Why are you doing it differently now?

Comment: @BalusC I did create JSF projects in the past but this one is a maven project, I want to make this simple hello world as a maven project. Ok I did remove `eager` and also added some scome`session` but I can't see the value in the screen. I should not be required to add the managed beans to the `faces-config.xml` manually right?

Comment: No, but to exclude the one and other, I would just try it.

Comment: I don't know if is appropiate to share files in stackoverflow. I tough to just create a tar.gz with the project and I uploaded it if someone wants to have a look: 2shared.com/file/h8VVRyqk/jsf2_tutorialtar.html ?

Probably the link will expire in few days.

Comment: After having downloaded several malicious software I finally got your project. But it's the raw Maven project structure, not the built WAR file. I'm not interested in the Maven project. I'm interested in the WAR file it has produced.

Comment: @BalusC Sorry about that. I cannot find the WAR file, it should be in the target folder of the project right? I think i need an special plugin to tell maven to create a `.war` I am trying to find the `.war` file but it is not in the target folder.

Comment: It's expected to be in the Tomcat deploy folder.

Comment: @BalusC I just checked, I don't have such folder. The project has  a folder called tomcat at `target>tomcat` and inside there I have other folders: `conf`,`logs`,`webapps`,`work` But the war is in none of them. To be honest I don't really understand how the app is deployed when using this embeded `mvn tomcat:run`

Comment: @BalusC I just generated a `.war` using `mvn package` command. 
It can be found at: http://www.2shared.com/file/FdqKGKTh/jsf2_tutorial-001-SNAPSHOT.html

It is the small link below for download the big one is probably just spam. It would be good if stackoverflow had a feature for uploading little files :)

Comment: Right, you're using Mojarra 2.1.0. I will update the answer.

Comment: @BalusC I also just posted an answer, please have a look and let me think what do you think about the solution I am using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've basically 2 problems:

1. JSF2 requires a minimum of Servlet 2.5 (Tomcat 6 compatible), yet your `web.xml` is declared conform Servlet 2.3 (Tomcat 4 compatible). You should declare your `web.xml` to highest version compatible with the servletcontainer. Given that it's Tomcat 6, which is a Servlet 2.5 container, declare it as Servlet 2.5 instead.

   ```xml
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <web-app 
       xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
       version="2.5">

       <!-- Config here. -->

   </web-app>
   ```

   *(yes, without the doctype!)*

   ---
2. `@ManagedBean` of Mojarra 2.1.0 doesn't work on Tomcat and Jetty due to accidently inserted Glassfish-specific code in the annotation scanning code. See also [issue 1937](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1937). You need to upgrade to at least Mojarra 2.1.1 (or just the currently available 2.1.17). An alternative is to manually register the managed bean in `faces-config.xml`, but that's plain clumsy.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, the `@ManagedBean(eager=true)` works on `@ApplicationScoped` only. Just omit it.

Comment: I just fixed my `web.xml` to use that code(without the doctype). The problem remains. This is the version of tomcat I am running with `mvn` Apache Tomcat/6.0.29

Comment: Yes, well I preffer to use JBoss, probably I will go back to it. Anyway it is good to know the exact reason why was not working. One thing I don't understand is how do I upgrade mojarra? Is that something I should add in the `pom.xml`? 
Thanks for your help BalusC.

Comment: You can find maven coordinates in the download page of almost every library which is also available by maven. In case of Mojarra, it's this page: http://javaserverfaces.java.net/download.html Replace the two entries for API and impl by the single entry `<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.17</version>
</dependency>`